# FormattedText.BuildGeometry dropping characters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to use FormattedText.BuildGeometry to determine how the characters are laid out, in order to determine the logical position of the mouse. In my context, the FormattedText can be assumed to be a single line - I should get a geometry group with 1 child, which has a child geometry for each character. This is true except that for the characters "f" and "t", repeating the character in the text of the FormattedText will cause the number of geometries on the line to be one less than the number of characters in the text.

Example code:

```
var tf = new Typeface(new FontFamily("Calibri"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Normal, FontStretches.Normal);
var ft = new FormattedText("ff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, tf, 14, Brushes.Black);
var g = ft.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));
var gc = (GeometryGroup)((GeometryGroup)g).Children[0];
Debug.Assert(gc.Children.Count == ft.Text.Length, "Expected length of " + ft.Text.Length + " but found " + gc.Children.Count);
```

You can just attach this to a button in an empty WPF application.

This fails for anything that contains "ff" or "tt". Changing the font changes the behaviour - some fonts I haven't found characters that cause this.

Comment: Here's the answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/ddd9c850-25a6-4b99-8a43-5816a0d329a1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `BuildGeometry` thinks in [glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph), not characters. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.buildgeometry.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Returns a Geometry object that represents the formatted text, **including all glyphs** and text decorations.

In several fonts, "ff" and "tt" are [ligatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), so they are represented by a single glyph.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288896/coordinates-of-a-specific-character-in-a-multi-lined-wpf-formattedtext) for an explanation of how to do what you wish. Basically, `BuildHighlightGeometry(Point, int, int)` can return the bounding box for individual characters. You can iterate over the bounding boxes and perform hit tests until you find the character that matches.